# Typescript coditional interface

Tags: typescript, oop, interface

I have 2 interfaces

```
interface i1 {
    x: number;
}

interface i2  {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    z: number
}

// ok
const o: i1 = {
    x: 1,
}

// ok
const o: i2 = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
}
```

I want to specify that if my object has `y` field it must have `z` field aswell

I 'm trying to solve it this way

```
    // expected error but everything is "fine"
    const o: i1 | i2 = {
        x: 1,
        y: 2,
    }
```

If I'm correct `{ x: number, y: number }` shouldn't match any of `i1` or `i2`.

What is correct approach for doing this? Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your union of `i1 | i2` exclusive. There are two ways to do that.

**Manually**

This will make sure `y` and `z` can never exist on `i1`.

```
interface i1 {
  x: number;
  y?: never;
  z?: never;
}
```

This change alone will give us the desired error.

**By using a helper**

We can create a helper that does the same thing but is reusable.

```
type DistributedKeyOf<T> =
T extends any
    ? keyof T
    : never;


type CreateExclusiveUnion<T, U = T> =
T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<DistributedKeyOf<U>, keyof T>, never>>
    : never;

type ExclusiveUnion<T> = CreateExclusiveUnion<T>;
```

Usage:

```
const oa: ExclusiveUnion<i1 | i2> = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly! Second part is exactly what I needed.